# Spark DataFrame convert element to String

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
+---+--------------------+
|idn|     recommendations|
+---+--------------------+
|463|[[10955,0.0086656...|
|496|[[12767,0.0209305...|
|148|[[9813,0.00673213...|
|471|[[8537,0.00546676...|
|243|[[10846,0.0044064...|
|623|[[10955,0.3857911...|
|540|[[11463,0.0250675...|
|392|[[7177,0.01615425...|
|737|[[7994,0.12720428...|
|516|[[10955,0.4047550...|
+---+--------------------+
```

and Schema like this:

```
dataFrame.printSchema()


 root
 |-- idn: long (nullable = true)
 |-- recommendations: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id_usn: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rating: double (nullable = true)
```

And now I want convert **id_usn** and **rating** in column **recommendations** to **String**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the nested struct column as below,

```
col_schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField('id_usn',StringType(),True),StructField('rating',StringType(),True)]))
df = dataFrame.select('idn',dataFrame.recommendations.cast(col_schema))
df.printSchema()
```

Please try this and let me know.